# Netlogo in Ubuntu: User interface not rendering correctly

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, rendering, ubuntu-12.04, netlogo

I am having graphics rendering issues on my user interface in Netlogo. When Netlogo first opens, many of the objects on the interface render as white until I specifically click on them. When I open a menu, it frequently leaves a white shadow after I click out of it, obscuring objects on the interface. Also, when I switch from the code to the interface window, left over code is still visible on the interface, sometimes obscuring buttons and sliders. If I minimize Netlogo, code and menu shadows are cleared, and the interface looks like it does when it first starts. Although it's still possible to use Netlogo, this is annoying and I would really appreciate being able to fix it.

I am running Netlogo 5.1.0 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with an AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series graphics card. I have also tried Netlogo 5.0.5 with the same results. I have not experienced rendering problems with any other programs in ubuntu.

I can give more specific details on the rendering issues if necessary, but it seems to be some sort of general graphics problem. Has anyone experienced this kind of problem before? Any ideas on things I might try to fix it or some place I could start to try to figure out what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Hum... I've been using NetLogo on various versions of Ubuntu (probably since 11.04) and never experienced anything like that. Maybe make sure your graphics driver is up to date? Or perhaps try to run it with a different JVM (e.g., Oracle instead of OpenJDK)? In any case, StackOverflow is not the proper platform for such a question. I'd suggest maybe http://ubuntuforums.org/ or maybe https://groups.yahoo.com/group/netlogo-users/ to see if anyone else ever experienced similar issues.

Comment: "perhaps try to run it with a different JVM" is the first thing I'd try

Comment: also asked on netlogo-users at http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Netlogo-in-Ubuntu-user-interface-graphics-rendering-issues-td5005116.html

Comment: NetLogo is an ordinary Java/Swing program, so I think it's unlikely this is actually NetLogo-specific. Do other Swing applications have similar problems?